# Enum query param does not work - openapi-generator

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I use `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` version `7.0.0` for OpenAPI swagger spec to Java code generation.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${openapi.generator.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I defined a query param as an Enum value

```
  parameters:
    - in: query
      name: status
      required: false
      example: scheduled, active
      schema:
        type: string
        enum: [scheduled, active]
```

but in the plugin-generated class, the property is not defined as an Enum

```
@Parameter(name = "status", in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) String status
```

So, the schema doesn't stop sending any values for this parameter.

I followed the rules in the [Swagger doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/) for Enum but suppose that's something plugin generation-specific

Is there any way to define a param as Enum type and allow the query param to accept only predefined values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried on my own and I find this solution to your problem.
**First of all** I defined the enum under the **component/schemas** section like:

```
component:
  schemas:
    status:
      type: string
      enum: [scheduled, active]
      default: active
```

Just insert the default attribute to set that value as the default one for your request.

**Then** just add the reference in the path (do not insert the enum inside the {}) and complete the definition with all the responses you need:

```
paths:
  /insertYourPathHere:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: productCode
          in: query
          required: false
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/status'
      responses: # add your api responses here
```

Finally, insert your yaml inside the *src/main/resources* folder and run the application with goal: *clean install*
All your classes will be created and you will have this:

```
@Parameter(name = "status", description = "", schema = @Schema(description = "", allowableValues = { "scheduled", "active" }, defaultValue = "active")) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false, defaultValue = "active") Status status
```

One **final consideration**.
If the parameter sent in the request will not match one of the value of your enum, an *IllegalArgumentException* exception will be raised. So only the defined value of your enum will be accepted.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. default set was not required for me.