# "schema" attribute missing in io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter annotation while openapi-generator-cli parsing openapi yaml to Java code

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am not getting "schema" attribute in following java code, after openapi-generator-cli parsed my yaml file to java code.

Enum yaml in my parameter header

```
- name: My-Header-Name
  in: header
  description: My header description
  schema:
    type: string
    enum:
      - ENUM-ONE
      - ENUM-TWO
```

Here I get "schema" attribute when I use `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli:5.4.0`

`@Parameter(name = "My-Header-Name", description = "My header description", schema = @Schema(description = "", allowableValues = { "ENUM-ONE", "ENUM-TWO" })) @RequestHeader(value = "My-Header-Name", required = false) String myHeaderName`

Here I DO NOT get "schema" attribute when I use `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli:7.0.1`

`@Parameter(name = "My-Header-Name", description = "My header description", in = ParameterIn.HEADER) @RequestHeader(value = "My-Header-Name", required = false) String myHeaderName`

Not sure this is a brakeage or I am missing some configuration. I faced this issue while upgrading my spring-boot service from 2.7 to 3.1. I had to upgrade openapi versions too.

Comment: This helped me fix the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77141755/enum-query-param-does-not-work-openapi-generator/77149137#77149137